# React Native universal apk crashes immediately

Tags: android, react-native, build

I was trying to generate separate apks per cpu architecture and also an universal apk. I set `enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true` and `universalApk true`. I was getting an error, so I also had to remove those lines:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
}
```

The generated `app-armeabi-v7a-release` works fine. But the universal apk crashes immediately.

Here's the error it shows.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.b(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.create(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.react.k$5.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

How do I fix this? Sounds like some native module is not being included in the universal apk. Is this because of the removed `abiFilters`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's been solved by using `gradle` version specified in `react-native` documentation.

In `/android/app/build.gradle` it should be:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

and as soon as I updated to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1` it started to fail with your error.

Comment: Using outdated libraries is not an acceptable solution.